# Dynamic width binding to the dropdown(Popup) used in custom combobox

Tags: wpf

I am using custom ComboBox with style, I want to set width of a Popup dynamically via coading so that to auto adjust the width of popup

[image: Change this to]

[image: this]

so I wanted to change Popup like second image dynamically(whatever may be thesize of ComboBox)
I am using style as follows

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#666666"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="28"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.5"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,3"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Grid>                            
                        <Popup Margin="1" x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="{Binding ActualWidth,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}}">
                            <Border Name="DropDownBorder" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" CornerRadius="0,0,4,4" BorderBrush="#FFbbbbbb">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFE9E9E9" Offset="1" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                                <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="true">
                                    <ItemsPresenter  />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>                           
                        <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource cmbToggle}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="false" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

<Style x:Key="cmbToggle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Name="cmbBorder" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="#FFaaaaaa" BorderThickness="1.5">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFE9E9E9" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#FFaaaaaa" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right">                                
                            <Polygon Name="pol" Fill="#FF787878" Points="4,9 8,14 12,9" Stroke="#FF787878" StrokeThickness="0" Margin="1 1 0 0">
                            </Polygon>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" TargetName="cmbBorder" Value="4,4,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

So My idea is to change width of Popup dynamically(Combobox width - togglebutton width = popup width).I have written style in App.xaml
How to do this, Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: WHy don't you check out the style of the default combobox and see how MS worked it out? As far as I remember what you want is default behavior of the combobox.

Comment: @Djerry No this is not the default behavior. Not at-least in Windows-8. Kind of glad this isn't the default behavior since with this required `Style`, every-time you use the "arrow" to toggle the `ComboBox` you need to move your mouse not just down but also left to make a selection which is just weird IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so in your `ToggleButton` `Style` we can see the `Border` holding `Polygon` arrow is 20 in `Width`. That's the `Width` to be removed from the `Popup`

Thus we can do something like:

Firstly add 2 Column's to the `Grid` in `ComboBox` `ControlTemplate`

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
  <Grid>
    <!-- New Bit -->
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- End of New Bit -->
    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    ...
```

and then update the `Width` of `Popup` to

```
<Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Width="{Binding Path=ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                      AncestorType=Grid}}"
...
```

Your `Style` already has `ColumnSpan` mentioned on appropriate controls, so nothing else is needed. This should give you the output your looking for.

Comment: perfect. Thanks a loooooooooot

Answer (score 1):

you can directly use

```
 <ComboBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="110"/>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Dhaval Patel's** solution bound to a view model property did the trick.
I calculate the max width using FormattedText when the collection changes and it bind it below.

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding MaxWidthOfMyCollection"/>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
```